# How to get a RoutedEvent knowing its name?

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to get a reference to a RoutedEvent given its name?

I tried `EventManager.GetRoutedEventsForOwner( typeof(ListBox) ).FirstOrDefault( r => r.Name == eventName )` but it return `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListBox` class defines no routed events. The `Selector` base class does though:

```
string eventName = "SelectionChanged";
var events = EventManager.GetRoutedEventsForOwner(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector)).FirstOrDefault( x=> x.Name == eventName);
```

Comment: I do not know the exact type at compile time, in practice i pass a Type as parameter. How can i get inherited routed events as well?

Comment: Use reflection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567944/getting-event-via-reflection

Comment: Already tried reflection, i extract the event correctly but  I found other complications. I use your solution and simply cycle over t.BaseType while != null. Thank You.